# Javascript increment up within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    for (i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
      $(".swipe-wrap").append("<div class=\"final\">Hello!</div>");
      console.log('hello');
    }
```

This is what I currently have. My `arrayData` is an array that changes each load.

How can I get it so my class `final` each `for` loop will have an counter like such : `<div class="final_1">Hello!</div>` , `<div class="final_2">Hello!</div>`..

Comment: the html is just a string,you know...`$(...).append('<div>' + i + '</div>');`

Comment: @MarcB Guess my heads been in my code too long lol. Now you point it out it's obvious, sorry for wasting your time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: why do you want to enumerate classes? I'm pretty confident, that you try to solve a different problem with this aproach.

Comment: @Thomas i'm making a slideshow based off an array. I never know what the array length is. So I create all the divs onto the page, then adding the classes based on the array. Below i'll do some logic to then add an image based on the the incremented class names

Comment: so you use this enumerated class as some kind of index/id to fetch the nth item with your js-code? well, this is bad ... practice. you always know how many images you have added yet. you can always fetch the added nodes and select the nth item of that list. way better than messing around with css-classes

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
  $(".swipe-wrap").append("<div class=\"final_"+i+"\">Hello!</div>");
  console.log('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not perform DOM manipulation inside loops. Always perform bulk operation.

Try this:

```
var html = ""
for (i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
  html += '<div class="final_'+i+'">Hello!</div>';
  console.log('hello');
}
$(".swipe-wrap").append(html);
```

You can also use `Array.forEach`.

```js
var html = ""
var arrayData = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"];
console.log(arrayData);
arrayData.forEach(function(item, index) {
  html += '<div class="tile final_' + index + '">Hello ' +item+ '!</div>';
  console.log('hello');
});
$(".swipe-wrap").append(html);
```

```css
.swipe-wrap {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.tile {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swipe-wrap"></div>
```